# Is it possible to use the Twitter API to feed tweets into a local text file?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using a projection mapping programme, with part of the project taking text from a local text file, and inserting it into the programme.

Instead of manually filling this text file with pre-populated content, is it possible to use the Twitter API to feed in tweets to this local text file?

Comment: So many ways to answer this question... You didn't mention anything about which language you're wanting to use, if you looked at any existing packages. Is it possible? Absolutely, but with little information it's hard to help.

Comment: Hoping to use javascript if it is possible with this language? What are some packages I could look at to get myself started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar using javascript to access twitter's API, but you should be able to achieve that using [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit).

Depending on the number of data you're wanting to obtain, the streaming API will be a better option. This will give you a large number of data with less likelihood of reaching a limit.

If you have more question regarding that specific package, you should give it a try (plenty of examples available) and post specific questions with proper tags (i.e. `javascript`, `twit`)